# File has unexpected size (250 != 140516). Mirror sync in progress?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, vmware-tools

I have had a Ubuntu 19.04 system. I upgraded it to 20.04 some how I found  Vmware tools were not giving desired results. So I decided to upgrade previously installed vmware tools. So I did following.

```
debian@osboxes:~$ sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

but while upgrading I got following errors

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  command-not-found-data diffstat example-content g++-8 gettext
  gir1.2-mutter-4 ifupdown intltool-debian libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg-perl
  libapt-pkg5.0 libarchive-zip-perl libasync-mergepoint-perl
  libcapture-tiny-perl libclass-factory-util-perl libclone-perl
  libdigest-bubblebabble-perl libdouble-conversion1 libebook-contacts-1.2-2
  libecal-1.2-19 libemail-valid-perl libfuture-perl libgnome-desktop-3-17
  libimport-into-perl libio-async-loop-epoll-perl libio-async-perl
  libio-pty-perl libio-string-perl libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libipc-run-perl
  libisl19 libjson-c3 liblinux-epoll-perl liblist-compare-perl libllvm8
  liblouisutdml8 libmoo-perl libmutter-4-0 libmysqlclient20 libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-dns-sec-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libosmesa6
  libparse-debianchangelog-perl libpath-tiny-perl libperlio-gzip-perl
  libpoppler85 libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
  libqt5test5 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libsereal-decoder-perl
  libsereal-encoder-perl libsereal-perl libstdc++-8-dev libstrictures-perl
  libstruct-dumb-perl libtagc0 libtest-refcount-perl libtexlua52
  libtext-levenshtein-perl libtype-tiny-perl libtype-tiny-xs-perl
  libunicode-utf8-perl libvpx5 libxml-simple-perl libyaml-libyaml-perl lintian
  multiarch-support patchutils pppconfig pppoeconf python3-cson python3-numpy
  python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-sip python3-speg
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  open-vm-tools-desktop
Suggested packages:
  cloud-init
Recommended packages:
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
The following packages will be upgraded:
  open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 151 not upgraded.
Need to get 688 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 open-vm-tools amd64 2:11.0.5-4ubuntu0.19.10.1 [547 kB]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 open-vm-tools amd64 2:11.0.5-4ubuntu0.19.10.1
  File has unexpected size (250 != 547012). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:bbb19129190dede6148f30b79fe04d2a996049b150dc308715d1041e6098784c
   - SHA1:cf49e32b07f318359128325769613abf6c385a87 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:66b78b7b1a39c03980a297325f80b043 [weak]
   - Filesize:547012 [weak]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 open-vm-tools-desktop amd64 2:11.0.5-4ubuntu0.19.10.1 [141 kB]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 open-vm-tools-desktop amd64 2:11.0.5-4ubuntu0.19.10.1
  File has unexpected size (250 != 140516). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:5cb835e57d4b93082bd692a9cba6e196cacd87ae39919f17a975defcbbdd3d2e
   - SHA1:637488a815726aa6e6f5a061c694923f10894be1 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:63619ce813958afe99d8ed690b540a27 [weak]
   - Filesize:140516 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/open-vm-tools/open-vm-tools_11.0.5-4ubuntu0.19.10.1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (250 != 547012). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:bbb19129190dede6148f30b79fe04d2a996049b150dc308715d1041e6098784c
    - SHA1:cf49e32b07f318359128325769613abf6c385a87 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:66b78b7b1a39c03980a297325f80b043 [weak]
    - Filesize:547012 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/open-vm-tools/open-vm-tools-desktop_11.0.5-4ubuntu0.19.10.1_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (250 != 140516). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:5cb835e57d4b93082bd692a9cba6e196cacd87ae39919f17a975defcbbdd3d2e
    - SHA1:637488a815726aa6e6f5a061c694923f10894be1 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:63619ce813958afe99d8ed690b540a27 [weak]
    - Filesize:140516 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What should I do in this case.

Comment: Have you tried `apt update --fix-missing`?

Comment: Simply try again, if you hadn't already. If the error is repeated: the files that were actually downloaded were both 250 bytes, and were downloaded over the HTTP protocol. There is a good chance that they actually contain an error message. Find the files `/var/cache/apt/archives/open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-desktop` and, if they are indeed 250 bytes, open them with `sudo less` and find out what's inside.